# WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: spring-mvc

Can someone please point to me what am I doing wrong here, this is the error message I'm getting;

```
 WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/logicalideasJPA/contacts.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'


<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:hibernate.properties" />

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.logicalideasJPA.persistence" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.logicalideasJPA.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.logicalideasJPA.dao" />

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Declare a JPA entityManagerFactory -->
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.logicalideasJPA.persistence" />
    <beans:property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</beans:bean>
```

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

@Autowired
private ContactsImp serviceInter;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showContactForm(Map<String, Contacts> map){
    Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
    map.put("contacts", contacts);
    return "contacts";
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
    and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

really appreciate some help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that it has to do with the fact you return contacts from your controller. The default view resolver is looking for a fitting HTML file to show the result.
Are you trying to return a response body entity or direct to a view page of some sort?

Comment: doesn't make sense though - the config above would make it direct to contacts.jsp - something looks to be missing..

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have a link on my index.jsp which takes me to contact(form) page. index page I can see fine problem is when I click on link it gives me this error.  WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/logicalideasJPA/contacts.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: True, but it seems like that view resolver is not actually chosen. Could it be the fact you return a string and not a full ModelAndView that causes this?

Comment: Silly me @Autowried the class and not the interface

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sending a request to "/logicalideasJPA/contacts.html" but there is no controller that is handling this request.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contacts")
public class ContactController {

@Autowired
private ContactsImp serviceInter;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showContactForm(Map<String, Contacts> map){
    Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
    map.put("contacts", contacts);
    return "contacts";
}
```

With the above change your request should be handled at /contacts uri

Comment: Thanks for you reply but I'm not having any joy. I think it's my web.xml file, correct me if I'm wrong the controller at this point is not being hit yet.  I'm clicking on a link from index.jsp to a contacts.jsp(form) which is in view folder.

Comment: Yes, your request is not reaching your controller. Your link in index.jsp should be to http://yoururl/contextpath/contacts , then it should reach your controller.

Comment: Do you mean something like this : <a href="/WEB-INF/views/contacts.jsp">Contacts</a>

Comment: I'm trying everything possible but still not getting to this link.

Comment: Try putting this link in your index.jsp : <a  href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/contacts">Contacts</a>

Comment: By clicking on that I get: message /logicalideasJPA/contacts
description The requested resource (/logicalideasJPA/contacts) is not available.